# Probability of more than 4 students pass the exam.

Tags: probability

Probability of a student pass the exam is $\frac{2}{3}$. If there is 7 student in the class, what is the probability of more than 4 students pass the exam.

(A)$\frac{33\cdot2^5}{3^7}$

(B)$\frac{35\cdot2^5}{3^7}$

(C)$\frac{37\cdot2^5}{3^7}$

(D)$\frac{38\cdot2^5}{3^7}$

(E)$\frac{39\cdot2^5}{3^7}$

My attempt :

Let P(A) is the probability of more than 4 students pass the exam.

Probability of 5 students pass the exam P(B): $\frac{2^5}{3^7}$

Probability of 6 students pass the exam P(C): $\frac{2^6}{3^7}$

Probability of 7 students pass the exam P(D): $\frac{2^7}{3^7}$

$P(A)=P(B)+P(C)+P(D)\\
P(A)=\frac{2^5\cdot7}{3^7}$

I think I'm doing the wrong way, but I don't know what to do to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preassuming independence the probability equals: $$P(X>4)=\sum_{k=5}^7P(X=k)$$where $X$ has [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters $n=7$ and $p=\frac23$.

So to be found is:$$\sum_{k=5}^7\binom7k\left(\frac23\right)^k\left(\frac13\right)^{7-k}$$

Comment: After doing the calculation from your answer, I found $\frac{203\cdot 2^5}{3^7}$ or around 2.97. Did my calculation wrong, Sir?

Comment: $\binom{7}{5}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{5}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2}+\binom{7}{6}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{6}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{1}+\binom{7}{7}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{7}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{0}=3^{-7}\times\left[21\times2^{5}+7\times2^{6}+1\times2^{7}\right]=3^{-7}\times1248$